# Converting a large CLOB object to .NET string to put into a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, datagrid, datagridview

I have created a Windows Forms GUI in C# that can display tabular data (results of an SQL query against an Oracle Server DB) in a DataGridView.
One of the field is an XML, potentially quite large, stored as a CLOB (Character Large OBject if I'm right).
Of course, the user will not directly look at the cell, he will rather double-click the cell to see the file pretty-printed.
The problem is that I need to convert the file (which is a CLOB) to a .NET String otherwise it generates an exception.
I have tried, as a workaround, to use the Oracle to_char procedure, but it is limited to 4000 characters. So I take a substring of the file like this:

```
 select to_char(dbms_lob.substr(column_name, 4000, 1 ))
```

The problem is, it doesn't display the whole file if it contains more than 4000 characters.
How could I circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the simple:

```
if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
{
    cellValue = "NULL";
}
else
{
    OracleLob clob = reader.GetOracleLob(i);
    cellValue  = (string) clob.Value;
}
```

Comment: It's too slow...is it possible to convert it to string on the server side?

Answer (score 3):

Don't store the CLOB, or the resultant string in the DataGridView.

Instead, capture the click event in the DataGridView then convert the CLOB to a string for viewing.  Use an appropriate encoding from `System.Text.Encoding`.

I'm assuming your DataReader or DataAdapter (whichever way you're filling the DataSet) will store your CLOB in a byte-array. (As it is with SQLServer and Informix drivers).

```
byte[] clob;
// get it from your datarow/datagridview bound item
string thexml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(theclob)
```

Comment: And how do you populate the byte array from the OracleDataReader object? There is a getOracleLob() method but no getOracleClob()...

Comment: I'm sorry -- I can't be specific to the Oracle driver as I've never used it.