# Oracle Clob to C# String

Tags: c#, oracle, api, web-services

I am using the **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client** to get data from Oracle into C#. My return value I am retrieving is a **Clob**:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Clob).Direction =
   ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

I cannot seem to *convert* this into a `string` or anything c# recognises.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/OracleClobClass.htm#ODPNT4145

Comment: How are you trying though? Clobs are streams so you'll probably be looking at something like `var s = new StreamReader(parameter.Value).ReadToEnd()`

Comment: I am doing, string test = cmd.Parameters["return_value"].Value.ToString(); but it isn't working. I tried new StreamReader(cmd.Parameters["return_value"].Value.).ReadToEnd(), but it is saying it cannot convert from object to System.IO.Stream

Comment: What is `cmd.Parameters["return_value"].Value.GetType()`?

Comment: The return value type is Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleClob

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleClobClass.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it with this:

```
OracleClob myLob = (OracleClob)cmd.Parameters[0].Value;
                    ret_string = Convert.ToString(myCLob.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like (where clob is your Clob)?

string clobValue  = (string) clob.Value;

According to this solution it should work:
[Converting a large CLOB object to .NET string to put into a DataGridView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736242/converting-a-large-clob-object-to-net-string-to-put-into-a-datagridview-cell/10815819)

Comment: When I do that, I get Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleClob. When I debug, I can go to cmd and then parameters, and then return_value, the value property has 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleClob', but when I expand Value, it has another value property with the string I want.